# Path for nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a nested resources but i am not get a path for these resources.

routes.rb

```
namespace :admin do
   resources :demos do
      resources :demojobs, :path => "jobs" do
        resources :demotutorials 
      end  
    end
end
```

I have try to get the new page of `demotutorials` page using following link:

```
new_admin_demo_demojob_demotutorials_path
```

but getting error

`No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"admin/demotutorials"}`

working with rails version : 3.2.11

Comment: can you post your controller path and directory of demotutorials_controller.rb file

Comment: You can check the names of the generated routes using the command `rake routes` on a terminal. Anyway, that many nested levels is not a good practice, check the docs https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#limits-to-nesting

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a redundant **s** at the end of your path, should probably be
`new_admin_demo_demojob_demotutorial_path` instead of `new_admin_demo_demojob_demotutorials_path`. You can check that by running `rake routes` in terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Once try like this,

```
demotutorials_url(1,2,3)
```

if it doesn't work check this link, However, what I've read from ROR guides is

Resources should never be nested more than 1 level deep.

http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/2/5/nesting-resources